# Which function satisfies this integral equation?

Tags: fourier-transform, integral-equations, integral-transforms

I am given the following integral equation to solve for $f(x)$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \ f(x-u) \ du = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Firstly, note that the LHS is *not* the convolution of $f(x)$ with itself, as may appear at a first glance. I tried to approach this using Fourier transform methods. Using the following definition:

$$\mathfrak{F}[f(x)] \equiv \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{iwx} \ dx$$

I get that the RHS transforms to:

$$\mathfrak{F}[\frac{1}{1+x^2}] = -(2 \pi)^{\frac{1}{2}} \ sinh(\omega)$$

However, I don't know how to tackle the LHS. It's the product of two functions of $x$, one of which is an integral. As stated above, the LHS is *not* a convolution and so it isn't simply $\mathfrak{F}[f(x)]^2$ (even if it was, the final solution would require the computation of the inverse fourier transform of $(-(2 \pi)^{\frac{1}{2}} \ sinh(\omega))^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which looks wholly intractable).

What is $f(x)$?

Comment: You can just factor out $f(x)$. It looks to me like $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: I appeciate that the $f(x)$ can be factored out of the integral, but I don't see how that leads to your answer exactly. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @CrossProduct Did you mean $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)f(x-u)\,du=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: No; the original post is correct, but as I wrote, at first glance it looks like it *should* be a convolution integral on the LHS. But it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)$ can be factored out of the integral, making a change of variables leads to
$$ \frac{1}{1+x^2}=f(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-u)\;du=f(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\;dt=cf(x) $$
where
$$ c=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\;dt$$
Now integrating both sides of $cf(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ yields $c^2=\pi$, so we can take $c=\sqrt{\pi}$. Therefore
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
is a solution to the equation.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks.